# Blank screen after resume from suspend

Tags: 12.10, suspend, lenovo

I have a new Lenovo z475 that I loaded Ubuntu 12.10 amd64+mac version onto. Everything works well except when I open the lid of my laptop after having closed it. It seems to freeze. I can't ping it or anything. I have AMD Vision Chipset. I have a Radeon HD 6520G using the x.org driver.

/var/log/pm-suspend.log shows:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager suspend suspend:
Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed.

Comment: You say you have ssh access? Does /var/log/syslog say anything usable? What happens when you restart the GUI with /etc/init.d/lightdm? If that doesn't work, it is probably a driver issue.

Comment: This happens to me all the time in linux :(

Comment: nothing in /var/log/syslog

Comment: i have been plagued by this bug on my old toshiba m70-113 laptop.. and couldnt use the sleep feature at all.it has never gotten into my head why is suspend feature so buggy on linux... as i never had any problems with windows!

Comment: Wasn't there a change in the kernel that effectively causes resume to be problematic? Something to do with secure boot? Also video drivers can cause the issue as well

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin looking for that information. Is there a log of known issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was graphical related after all. Switching to the proprietary FGLRX driver fixed my issue. Thanks for all those helpful comments.

Comment: First point on my consider list, mmm...

Comment: Yes, it was the general area, but no specific solution was given.

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo API for advanced power management (APM) is extremely poor. I went through 3 Lenovos with Ubuntu and Fedora distros and it was never 100% reliable. It recognizes the lid being closed occasionally when you get it up and running. Even suspend/resume was iffy.

Even my Desktop works 90% of the time. There are many causes and they all need to be tested, mine happens to be the Video Driver.

Consider:

- Graphics Drivers
- Virtual Machine Kernels
- Advance Power Management (As already mentioned)
- WiFi drivers (Sleep mode on driver)

Lots of things you need to test out, sometimes one of these will work, but most of the time its the fault APM API's, especially in Lenovos case.

Comment: My problem is a consistent problem, not an iffy one. I constantly get this error in the suspend log. There are many articles of people fixing the same problem with other laptops, there should a fix for this one. It only requires that the person who is aware of it, share it.

Comment: Agreed, hope you find a solution, but having installed Linux from early Fedora versions when Ubuntu wasn't even around with laptops and desktops, APM has always been iffy in all Linux kernels (IMHO)